# Dblink works independently but it doesn't work in a postgresql trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, dblink

I have the following dblink as an example:

```
select a.b 
from dblink('host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=test user=proof password=proof',
            'select id from project') as a(b int);
```

It works perfectly when I run it independently from the PgAdmin, but when I put it in a trigger returns an error that says that the function dblink(unknown,unknown) does not exist.

I have several dblink functions, some inserts, updates, etc, all work fine except when I put them on a trigger, sometimes the function error show the parameters (unknown,unknown) and sometimes (unknown,text), I even cast the parameters but still shows me the same error. Its driving me crazy.

Comment: Need to check the permissions that are responsible for executing the trigger. Might be they don't have access to dblink module or the other data source.

Comment: Possibly a search path issue. Try calling `your_schema_name.dblink(...)`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having similar problem.